# Grub errors installing applications dual boot Kali / Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, kali

I have dual boot Kali / Ubuntu laptop.  The boot Menu is Kali's and I can select to boot Kali or Ubuntu and booting works as expected, however any time I do a apt-get install on Ubuntu I get grub errors like the following:

```
 dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd-64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit code status 1
```

How do I stop getting grub errors when I install new software on my Ubuntu system while still being able to dual boot Kali and Ubuntu?

Comment: It sounds like Ubuntu does not like the boot from Kali. You can install Ubuntu's grub by booting into Ubuntu and reinstalling grub from there. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: The problem I have there is that I can't get the option to boot Kali from the Ubuntu grub if I remember correctly.